# Creating a 3rd Array from 2 different sized Arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a 3rd array from Array A and Array B, where Array B is contained within Array A. To keep it short I will just post the loop here, The arrays that I want are correct, I have already printed them and confirmed they are correct. It is just going somewhere wrong in my loop.

```
Array A: [a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3] 
Array B: [a1, a2, a3, b1, b3, c1, c2] 
Array C (what I want): [a1, a2, a3, b1, N/A, b3, c1, c2, N/A]
```

I think my error is coming from where my Next i is placed. I cannot put it inside the If statement but I am not sure where it should go.

```
For j = 1 To UBound(EASR_VI_New)
    For i = 1 To UBound(VI_VRR4)
        If VI_VRR4(i, 1) = EASR_SS_VI_All(j, 1) Then
            TE_VRR4E(i, 1) = TE_VRR4F(i, 1)
        ElseIf VI_VRR4(i, 1) <> EASR_SS_VI_All(j, 1) Then
            TE_VRR4E(i, 1) = "N/A"
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Currently the Array TE_VRR4E is printing all N/A, however when I print VI_VRR4 and EASR_SS_VI_All the first 3 values in each array are the exact same. So I don't know why it is giving me all N/A.

Comment: Your macro is trying to fill an array based on EASR_SS_VI_All if VI_VRR4 doesn't have the value it will print N/A, is that your goal?

Answer (score 2):

It is putting all `N/A` because it is continuing to loop and check even after finding the match.  The next loop then covers up the correct return with `N/A` because the next value in Array B does not equal the value in Array A being tested.

Default the `N/A` and exit the loop if positive.

```
For i = 1 To UBound(VI_VRR4)
    TE_VRR4E(i, 1) = "N/A"
    For j = 1 To UBound(EASR_VI_New)        
        If VI_VRR4(i, 1) = EASR_SS_VI_All(j, 1) Then
            TE_VRR4E(i, 1) = TE_VRR4F(i, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

---

To show it works:

```
Dim A As Variant, B As Variant, C As Variant, i As Long, j as Long

A = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A9").Value
B = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B7").Value

ReDim C(1 To UBound(A, 1), 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To UBound(A, 1)
    C(i, 1) = "N/A"
    For j = 1 To UBound(B, 1)
        If A(i, 1) = B(j, 1) Then
            C(i, 1) = A(i, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(A, 1), 1).Value = C
```

[image]

---

BTW: this same output can be done with a simple formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,B:B,1,FALSE),"N/A")
```

[image]

Comment: This loop won't work as i is undefined until inside the loop. Also is Exit Loop a command within VBA? I have never seen it used before.

Comment: @plungeintome see edit, i flipped the loops and yes `Exit Loop` is a vba command

Comment: @plungeintome no `Exit Loop` does not exist.  see edit.  Should be `Exit For`

Comment: for some reason this is still giving me all N/A's. Even with the Exit For

Comment: I will attempt to post the arrays that are being compared and what I should get. There are over 1500 inputs in the array. will only do first 10.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will have to take a closer look and see where else it could be going wrong in my code.

Comment: The whole A B thing was just a simple way to put it. I have 15 spreadsheets and over 1500 rows of data on each spreadsheet. I appreciate it though.

Comment: I am just an idiot. It is working for me... I just had the print line for the output array commented out, so i thought it was printing N/A but it in fact is just wasn't changing.

Comment: @plungeintome please consider marking one of the answers as correct.  You would mark the one that your ended up using as the correct answer.  You mark by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Scott has diagnosed your problem.

I post this just because it's a way of avoiding 2 loops.

```
Sub x()

Dim A As Variant, B As Variant, C() As String, i As Long

A = Array("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3")
B = Array("a1", "a2", "a3", "b1", "b3", "c1", "c2")

ReDim C(UBound(A))
For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
    If IsNumeric(Application.Match(A(i), B, 0)) Then
        C(i) = A(i)
    Else
        C(i) = "N/A"
    End If
Next i

Range("A1").Resize(, i) = C

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: if I want this in column form do I transpose or can I do Resize(i, )?

Comment: `Range("A1").Resize(i) = application.transpose(C)`.